# How to create subdomain link to SQL Server 2008

Tags: subdomain, godaddy, iis7, sql-server

I would like to know how to create a subdomain that is a link to an SQL Server database. I have Windows Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008. I have a static IP on the Windows server, and I have a domain at GoDaddy with the `A` host record pointing to the static IP.

I can successfully establish a remote connection to the SQL Server instance through SQL Server Management Studio. But I have to use the `www.mydomain.com` instead of something like `sqldbmain.mydomain.com`, which is what I would prefer to use.

For another example, if I create a SQL database at some web host like GoDaddy, they give me an external link to my DB like `sqldb1234.db.hostedresource.net`. That is what I'm trying to replicate.

I'm not sure whether this is something that has to be managed through IIS on the Windows server, through the domain management at GoDaddy, or through SQL Server management, or even a little bit of all of them.

**EDIT**

For clarification, I'm accessing the database through SQL Server Management studio. In the field where it asks for the "Server Name" is where I enter `www.mydomain.com`, but I would like to enter the value similar to `sqldb1234.db.mydomain.com`.

Comment: How did you access the SQL Server database through a browser previously (i.e., using the IP address)?

Comment: @dan: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an A record for `sqldb1234.db` in your DNS area for GoDaddy.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/2290/how-do-i-create-a-subdomain-in-simple-control-panel

Once the A record has propagated you should be able to use the subdomain `sqldb1234.db.mydomain.com` in your connection string.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds very promising; I will try it. I am curious, if create that A record and it points to the same IP as the `@` record, then will `sqldb1234.db` basically be an alias to the `www`? I mean, wouldn't `www.mydomain.com` and `sqldb1234.db.mydomain.com` both allow a successful connection to the database?

Comment: That was what I needed. I understand now why it helps to use the A host record. Since I can control which IP the subdomain points to, if I need to move the SQL Server to a server with a different IP later, then I can just update the IP in A record and my URL stays valid. All the little dots are connected now :) Thanks again!

Comment: That's right! Glad I could help :)